# Regex replace everything after specific character inside specific tag

Tags: regex, coda

I have a list of XML elements with values. I'd like to remove any characters or numbers after a specific character (in this case, a period), but only within the *someTag* element.

```
<someTag>123.3</someTag>
<someTag>8623.34</someTag>
```

I'm able to target periods inside the tag using: `\.(?=[^<]*</someTag>)`. However, I can't figure out how to remove the period and everything after it so that the end result would be:

```
<someTag>123</someTag>
<someTag>8623</someTag>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern only matches the period. You have to capture everything after it till the tag's closing too. Try this:

```
(\.[^\<]+)<\/someTag>
```

`[^\<]+` is a negated character set, meaning it will match anything not in the set. `[^\<]+` matches until it encounters a `<` character.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tF5iH3/1)

Comment: Nice! This selects everything after the period, including the closing </someTag>. Out of curiosity, is there a way to keep the closing tag intact, so it doesn't get removed as well? (Note, you could just replace everything with the closing </someTag> which would work the same way). Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to replace the whole match, extract the first capture group and replace it with an empty string.